# What is the difference between Groovy's "execute" method and running bash commands normally?

Tags: java, bash, curl, groovy, bitbucket

I'm trying to use Bitbucket's API to generate a new access key from a refresh key. I can successfully do this in the terminal using:

```
curl -X POST -u "${client_id}:${secretKey}" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=${refreshToken}
```

Where ${...} have been replaced by their literal values. It correctly returns something similar to this:

```
{"access_token": "xxxxx", "scopes": "pullrequest", "expires_in": 3600, "refresh_token": "xxxxx", "token_type": "bearer"}
```

I'm using Groovy to execute this:

```
def getAccessToken = "curl -X POST -u \"${client_id}:${secret}\" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=${refreshToken}"
def getAccessTokenResult = getAccessToken.execute().text
```

When I println the command and run the result it will work, so it is not a malformed URL. When I println the result of the command itself, it comes back with this:

```
{"error_description": "Invalid OAuth client credentials", "error": "unauthorized_client"}
```

There is no reason this should be happening unless there is a fundamental difference between how the commands are being run, if anybody knows the difference or can even solve this issue, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You are using a lot of shell variables in the `curl` command in Groovy. Do they have values when you run the Groovy code? (Most likely, you need to export them before running. Otherwise, the `curl` command that actually runs probably looks like `curl -X POST -u ":" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=`.

Comment: @chepner Answering for OP here - the parsing of the string is done before it is executed. A `println` of `getAccessToken` shows the full `curl` command with all values correctly populated; that command can be pasted into the terminal and run directly (and gives the result we're expecting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested both methods using https://httpbin.org/ and discovered that the `Authorization` header returned by the server was different with each method.

I believe that wrapping your credentials (`-u`) in double-quotes in your shell simply tells the shell they're meant to be treated as a single argument. They are not passed to `curl`.

It looks like Groovy includes the quotes as part of the argument. Removing them generates the same `Authorization` header in both the shell and Groovy, but of course now you might need to escape certain characters in your client ID and secret key values:

```
... -u ${client_id}:${secretKey} ...
```